# Как мне посмотреть какой идет запрос в БД?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, datatable

У меня есть таблица DataTables, Server-side у меня php
делал по примеру: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
У меня сейчас работает фильтр, поиск, сортировка. Как мне получить запрос в БД который передает DataTables для того что бы потом создать кнопку експорта в xls(x) с помощью PHPExcel? у меня в БД 75k+ записей а стандартный метод експорта експортирует только 10 записей и все! Или подскажите как мне осуществить експорт с параметрами фильтра, поиска, и если записей будет например 10k+ ?
 вот сам файл с кодом для вывода таблицы: http://pastebin.com/VSU2H57t
вод код куда я подключаю сам клас

```
<?php
// DB table to use
$table = 'dbname';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'codename',   'dt' => 15 ),
    array( 'db' => 'threat_type',   'dt' => 16 ),
    array( 'db' => 'os',   'dt' => 17 ),
    array( 'db' => 'full_url',   'dt' => 18 ),
    array( 'db' => 'image_url',   'dt' => 19 ),
    array( 'db' => 'assigned_to',   'dt' => 20 ),
    array( 'db' => 'status',   'dt' => 21 )

);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'user',
    'pass' => 'pass',
    'db'   => 'db',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( '../ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего перед отправкой запроса вывести его в лог -

```
$sql = "какой-то запрос "."какие-то условия";
error_log($sql); 
...
```

Comment: смотрите, все работает отлично! НО експорт експортирует только то что на данный момент показано в таблице(например первые 10 записей) а я хочу експортировать все записи которые отфильтровал datatables

Comment: ну так у вас проблема с сервером бд, который не отдает данные, или с клиентом, который из полученных данных не может экспортировать в excel? ничего не понятно.
Вам нужно в PHP делать конверсию массива полученного от бд и отправлять клиенту csv или excel файл

Comment: Все работает прекрасно(я про фильтр и вывод),я хочу все експортировать.Например юзер фильтрует только по 4 колонкам(а их например 10),или фильтр только по date range,вот я и хочу что бы мне вернулся ответом не заметно для юзера сам SQL запрос для того что бы я дальше через кнопку послал юзера на страницу создания xls,которая с помощью того SQL запроса выводит из БД записи и генерирует XLS файл для скачивания.Думаю понятно написал.Я понимаю что я придумал что то ужасное,но поиск в гугле ничего подходящего не нашел,а точнее вообще не нашел реализацию експорта DataTables с помощью Server-side php

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо сделать так, чтобы PHP скрипт можно было бы вызывать без значения страницы и её размера - как пример, MySQL запрос в себе имеет ограничения по началу записи и их количеству как в [примере](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql) с линии 59:

```
/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}
```

Вам надо НЕ передавать эти параметры, или передавать -1 как условно, чтобы при проверке на это значение ограничения бы не использовались:

```
/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && ($_GET['iDisplayStart'] != -1) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}
```

В вашем конкретном случае делаете вот это перед обращением за информацией:

```
unset($request['start']);
```

Comment: а как тогда будет себя вести сервер если мы сразу поставим на вывод все записи ( -1) ??? 75 000 + записей 100% все не подгрузит и выведет ошибку 500.

Comment: Думаю нормально, это не так много. Если не хватает времени, используйте set_time_limit в функции создания отчета ДО обращения к БД.